# How to make generic method for extracting different types from Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, generics, .net-core

I want to make one method which will be responsible to get value based on input arg key and to lookup for type of that value because its an object (can be int, string, datetime...)

I created something like this:

```
public T GetValueForKeyFromHeader<T> (string key)
{
 object value = null;
 var hasValue = Headers?.TryGetValue(key, out value!); //IDcitionary<string, object>
 return (T)Convert.ChangeType(typeof(value), typeof(T)); 
//here on this line I have an error: 'value' is a variable but its used like a type
}
```

some examples of this IDictionary collection:
//"apiKeyId", "guid"
//"CorrelationId", 333
// "test": "hello world"

I want to extract these values, and to put them in my non-anemic model for each property:

```
public string Test{get;set;} = GetValueForKeyFromHeader("test");
public int CorrelationId{get;set;} = GetValueForKeyFromHeader("CorrelationId");
public string ApiKeyId {get;set;} = GetValueForKeyFromHeader("api_key_id");
```

Comment: Apparently you meant `value.GetType()`?

Comment: The issue here is that headers can have more than one value, and you were looking for a single value.

Comment: Yes I already tried with `value.GetType()` but then in the caller prop `public string? CorrelationId { get; set; } = GetValueForKeyFromHeader("CorrelationId");` I have following error:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0411?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0411)

Comment: @JohnWu basically I need to extract all value items from all items of IDictionary object..

Comment: @Stefan0309 So have you tried specifying the type argument that cannot be inferred? Such as `GetValueForKeyFromHeader<string>("CorrelationId")`?

Comment: yes you are right, but still I have an error on my prop: 
```public string HttpMethod
        {
            get { return GetValueForKeyFromHeader<string>("http_method"); }
            
        }```
error is: `HttpMethod = 'eventData.HttpMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'`
It never enters to this method `GetValueForKeyFromHeader<string>("http_method")`

Comment: You pass two types to `Convert.ChangeType`, the first argument should be an object that needs to be converted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-7.0) incorrectly, you need to pass the object that you want to convert.

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
```

Seeing as you're not actually using the result of `TryGetValue`, it may also be simpler to simply access the object by its key. If it doesn't exist you'll get a `KeyNotFoundException`, in my opinion this would be more clear than the `InvalidCastException` you'll currently receive for passing `null`.

```
var value = Headers[key];
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, TypeDescriptor is the way to go :

```cs
public static bool TryGetValue<TValue>(this IDictionary<string, object> self, string key, out TValue value)
{
    if (!self.TryGetValue(key, out var _value))
    {
        value = default;
        return false;
    }
    if (_value is TValue casted)
    {
        value = casted;
        return true;
    }
    if (_value is string str)
    {
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(TValue));
        if (converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
        {
            value = (TValue)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(str);
            return true;
        }
    }
    value = default;
    return false;
}
```

Then you can rewrite your method:

```cs
public T GetValueForKeyFromHeader<T> (string key)
{
    return Headers?.TryGetValue(key, out var value) == true ? value : default;
}
```